# Strange issue with shader constants (with a scent of SharpDX)

Tags: shader, constants, directx-11, sharpdx, light

I want to use lights in my shader that I can set when I desire, the first and second light get the values I want in them, the third light does not seem to...

I have this as my shader code (a bit messy but I will clean it after this):

```
struct VS_IN
{
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float4 norm : NORMAL;
    matrix instance : INSTANCEMATRIX;
};

struct PS_IN
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 norm : NORMAL;
};

cbuffer world : register (b0)
{
    matrix world;
}

cbuffer viewProj : register (b1)
{
    matrix viewProj;
}

cbuffer material : register (b2)
{
    float4 color : COLOR;
}

cbuffer lights : register (b3)
{
    float4 Light1Color;
    float3 Light1Direction;

    float4 Light2Color;
    float3 Light2Direction;

    float4 Light3Color;
    float3 Light3Direction;
}

PS_IN VS( VS_IN input )
{
    PS_IN output = (PS_IN)0;

    output.pos = mul(input.pos, input.instance);
    //output.pos = mul(output.pos, world);
    //output.pos = mul(input.pos, world);
    output.pos = mul(output.pos, viewProj);
    output.norm = normalize(mul( input.norm, input.instance));
    //output.col = input.col;

    return output;
}

float4 PS( PS_IN input ) : SV_Target
{
    return Light3Color;//float4(Light3Direction.r, Light3Direction.g, Light3Direction.b, 1.0f);// + float4(0.2f,0.2f,0.2f,0.9f);
    //return color;
}
```

I have a Light struct defined as follows:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
struct Light
{
    public Color4 Color; 
    public Vector3 Direction;
    float padding;

    public Light(Color color, float directionX, float directionY, float directionZ)
    {
        Direction = new Vector3(directionX, directionY, directionZ);
        Color = color;
        padding=0;
    }
}
```

I create my lightbuffer like this:

```
_lightBuffer = new Buffer(_device, Utilities.SizeOf<Matrix>(), ResourceUsage.Default, BindFlags.ConstantBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.None, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);
_device.ImmediateContext.PixelShader.SetConstantBuffer(3, _lightBuffer);
```

and fill it using:

```
Light[] lights = new Light[]
                {
                    new Light(Color.Red, 0.5f,0.5f,0.5f),
                    new Light(Color.Blue, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f),
                    new Light(Color.White, 1, 1, 1),
                };
                _device.ImmediateContext.UpdateSubresource(lights, _lightBuffer);
```

If I return either Light1Color or Light2Color in my pixelshader, I get the expected result (red or blue), if I return Light3Color, all I get is my background color...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you checking your light color vector to ensure your alpha is not being set? Try changing Light 3 from white to something like green or yellow to ensure it is a problem with the light itself and not the color.

Comment: I did change that light to green, it had no effect. Turns out it had to do with the way I write the data into the buffer. The code in my own answer solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the way I wrote the data in the constant buffer was wrong/misunderstood/incomplete, the following method works fine:

```
                var lightStreamLength = Light.SizeInBytes * lights.Length;
                var lightStream = new DataStream(lightStreamLength, true, true);
                for (int i = 0; i < lights.Length; i++)
                {
                    lightStream.Write(lights[i]);
                }
                lightStream.Position = 0;
                _lightBuffer = new Buffer(_device, lightStream, lightStreamLength, ResourceUsage.Default, BindFlags.ConstantBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.None, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);
                lightStream.Dispose();
                context.PixelShader.SetConstantBuffer(3, _lightBuffer);
```